# Save output into variable

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, macos

i have tried for like 30 minutes. Whats wrong with this code ? :(
Input :

```
var = `cat marktplatz.html | grep -m 1 "post" | grep -o -E '\b(jobs/.*htm)' `
```

Output :

```
var: command not found
```

Comment: Apart from the spacing issue, this is a [useless use of cat](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html).  It can be written more succinctly as `grep -m 1 "post" < marktplatz.html | grep -o -E '\b(jobs/.*htm)'` -- or even as `< marktplatz.html grep -m 1 "post" | grep -o -E '\b(jobs/.*htm)'`

Comment: Thanks Keith, .. i am new to bash and programming. Good to know, that this code can be optimized. Always willing to learn from the experienced guys ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var = BLABLA
```

should be

```
var=BLABLA
```

The first form is interpreted as running the command `var` with `=` as the first argument.